Retrive stripe fee for a payment intent
I have created a payment intent of $75 for US-Bank transfer. I have transfer $75 for the banking instructions provided(domestic_wire_us) and the payment intent is marked as succeeded. When I retrieve the payment intent, I see only $0.38 as fee. But since it is a wire transfer, there is a additional $15 fee which I can see in balance dashboard. So, $0.38(Stripe processing fee)+$15(Wire transfer fee) is the total fee associated with this payment. I can't find $15 fee details in the payment intent.
This is how, I retrieved the payment intent:
"https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/" + paymentIntentId + '?expand[]=latest_charge.balance_transaction'

My questions is:

When payment intent for bank transfer is succeeded, how do I know whether it is regular bank transfer or wire transfer?
How can I retrieve all the fees associated with a payment intent?

Can somebody please help me regarding this

I'm not familiar with all this or what your 'wire transfer' is, but sometimes Stripe fees are just taken as adjustments from your balance on e.g a monthly basis, not as part of the balance_transaction associated with a certain payment. In those cases you'd use reports like https://docs.stripe.com/reports/balance since you can't really connect things using the API. Not sure if it's that. Really it's a question for Stripe support, not SO!

@karllekko Thanks for the reply. I have to deduct the stripe fee from user deposit amount. If stripe fees are taken from platform balance, its not possible to know whether stripe has adjusted fee from main platform balance

I can see the $15.00 you're referring to here https://stripe.com/pricing/local-payment-methods. I'm not familiar with this APM either, but I wonder if that fee is truly separate, or if it's summed up for the day like a lot of Stripe's other extra fees work. If it's separate, there may be some info in the balance_transaction.description to tie it up to the payment. However since this fee isn't variable, could you not just infer it automatically from all payments using this APM?

"How do I know whether it is regular bank transfer or wire transfer?" To confirm on your end, but I believe bank transfers are us_bank_account while wire trransfers are customer_balance
